# Estrutura de repetição for em C

Tags: c, if, for

Boa tarde, estava criando um código em C onde quero que seja mostrado a quantidade de números pares que foram digitados pelo usuario. Porem, ao acrescentar o valor na variavel "q" , simplesmente nao acrescenta, fica como 0.
Alguem sabe como arrumar esse erro?

```
int main () {

int cont,v,q;

q=0;

for (cont = 1; cont <= 6;cont++){

printf("\n Digite um valor: ");
scanf(" %d",&v);

if (v % 2 ==0)
q= q++;

} 
printf("existem %d numeros pares\n",q);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: apenas altera  **q=q++;** para **q++;** e a variavel **q=0;** ao declara-la jé é zero, ao atribuir **q=0;** para min parece que reforça que realmente **q** sera iniciada por zero...Apenas isso a terá um contador de números pares.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unica alteração que realizei foi no acrescento do contador de números pares.
Também deixei seu código identado, é uma boa prática na programação.
Segue abaixo o código funcional e identado.

```
int main () {

int cont,v,q;

q=0;

for (cont = 1; cont <= 6;cont++){

    printf("\n Digite um valor: ");
    scanf(" %d",&v);

    if(v % 2 ==0){
        q= q+1;
    }
} 
printf("existem %d numeros pares\n",q);

return 0;
}
```